# GWT form pass a int to a doGet() servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I have a form submission to a servlet with a doGet() method. What I need is to pass an id to the servlet via doGet() and retrieve it in that method.

What I tried so far: adding an id as a query string and using request.getParameter() in the doGet. I am using this same method in doPost() and its working.

**client side code**

```
downloadPanel = new FormPanel();
downloadPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
downloadPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);

downloadPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"downloadfile" + "?entityId="+ 101);
downloadPanel.submit();
```

**server side servlet**

```
public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet {

private String entityId;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

entityId = request.getParameter("entityId");
```

entityId is null. How can i pass an Id to the doGet() request?
As for looking at examples online this should work as it works for the doPost() as is. Thanks as i am stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameters are ignored in the action field ([submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)). You should add it as a hidden parameter ([how can i add hidden data on my formPanel in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181149/how-can-i-add-hidden-data-on-my-formpanel-in-gwt)):

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED); // use urlencoded
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);
FlowPanel fields = new FlowPanel(); // FormPanel only accept one widget
fields.add(new Hidden("entityId", "101")); // add it as hidden
form.setWidget(fields); 
form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "downloadfile");
form.submit(); // then the browser will add it as query param!
```

If you do not use `urlencoded` it will be available using the `request.getParameter(…)` too, but it will be transferred in the body instead of the URL.

Comment: This works great. Thanks for taking the time to help me. Its very appreciated. I never seen this come up in any of my searches. You nailed it. Thanks

Comment: This solution causes a problem. "com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget"  I have a drop down and when i select an item i pass the id as hidden. So, this form gets called everytime i make a new selection. I commented out the hidden and no error. Is there a way to clear it and then re add it?

Comment: What i ended up doing is creating a new hidden then attaching it so then after the form is sent i remove it. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to add acontainer panel, for example a FlowPanel. I'll update the example later.